# If a DibSection is independent of any device, why does it need a device context?

Tags: winapi, gdi

When creating a bitmap you have <strike>three</strike> four choices:

- [**CreateBitmap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap): creates a device-dependent bitmap *(and it better be compatible with the device you eventually intend to use it on)*
- [**CreateCompatibleBitmap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap): creates a device-dependent bitmap *(compatible with the DC you supply)*
- **[CreateDIBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibitmap)**: creates a device-dependent bitmap, but lets you specify the device-independent bits to initialize the bitmap with<sup>[1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=95875)</sup>  *(functionally equivalent to calling **CreateCompatibleBitmap** + **SetDIBits**)*
- **[CreateDIBSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection)**: *creates a device-independant bitmap (but i have to supply a DC?)*

It makes sense why **CreateCompatibleBitmap** would need an `hdc` parameter: it has to know which DC to be compatible with.

> <strike>**Note**: It doesn't make sense why **CreateBitmap** **doesn't** take an `hdc`. How does it know what DC to be compatible with?</strike>
>
> **CreateBitmap** doesn't take a DC, and it **doesn't** know what DC to be compatible with. That's your job. And you better make sure it's compatible with the DC you eventually intended to use it with.

Why does **CreateDIBSection** take a handle to a device context?

> ## CreateDIBSection function
>
> The CreateDIBSection function creates a DIB that applications can write to directly. The function gives you a pointer to the location of the bitmap bit values. You can supply a handle to a file-mapping object that the function will use to create the bitmap, or you can let the system allocate the memory for the bitmap.

```
| Function               | Type | Takes hdc |
|------------------------|------|-----------|
| CreateBitmap           | DDB  | No        |
| CreateCompatibleBitmap | DDB  | Yes       |
| CreateDIBitmap         | DDB  | Yes       |
| CreateDIBSection       | DIB  | Yes       |
```

What's the deal with DIBs?

<strike>**Bonus Question**</strike>

Q. What's the deal with **CreateBitmap**?

A. It's up to you to ensure it's compatible. Good luck! Or you can just use **CreateCompatibleBitmap**

## Bonus Reading

- Raymond Chen's Old New Thing: [A survey of the various ways of creating GDI bitmaps with predefined data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=95875). An **excellent** write-up of the different methods of creating Bitmaps in GDI.

Comment: Did you look at the docs? *If the value of iUsage is DIB_PAL_COLORS, the function uses this device context's logical palette to initialize the DIB colors.*

Comment: @JonathanPotter And if `iUsage` is `TBD`?

Comment: You draw using an HDC, so if you didn't provide the one to link to the DIB section, how would you do anything with it? (And the `TBD` which is currently cluttering most of MSDN's WinAPI documentation are placemarkers for *To Be Determined*, which has apparently not yet been decided.) `CreateBitmap` does not require one because you have to select it: **After a bitmap is created, it can be selected into a device context by calling the SelectObject function. However, the bitmap can only be selected into a device context if the bitmap and the DC have the same format.**

Comment: I don't have to draw with a DIBSECTION (i could save it. I could convert to a GDI+ bitmap, i could convert it to an IWicBitmap). A Compatible bitmap also has to be selected; why does it need a DC when CreateBitmap does not.

Comment: The `HDC` is necessary when using `DIB_PAL_COLORS`, as documented. Otherwise it's optional.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that HDC is optional. The documentation doesn't say HDC can be empty. And given the [basic ground rules of programming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060320-13/?p=31853): HDC must be valid. If it turns out the documentation is simply wrong, and HDC **is** optional, and HDC is only used if `iUsage` is `DIB_PAL_COLORS`, then that can be phrased in the form of an answer and get an accept.

Comment: These functions date back to the stone age when video adapters could display only 16 or 256 colors and nobody could afford enough RAM to create a 24bpp bitmap.  A 640x480x3 bitmap takes 900KB, you only had 640.  Your current desktop wallpaper bitmap takes more space than the entire OS install back then.  Palettes were not optional, so HDC wasn't.  Time to move ahead already, GDI+ has been around for 20 years.

Comment: `CreateDIBSection` works if you pass `NULL` for the `HDC`, you can demonstrate this empirically simply by trying it. But it's not documented as such so I'm not really sure what you're looking for in an answer, unless someone from Microsoft with access to the source code wants to weigh in.

Comment: Raymond Chen [would be rolling in his grave](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050901-17/?p=34343)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be:

- the `hdc` is only needed if `usage = DIB_PAL_COLORS`
- otherwise (i.e. `usage = DIB_RGB_COLORS`) then `hdc` *may* be optional